# How to join tables from two different databases using sqlalchemy expression language / sqlalchemy core?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, cross-database

I am using MySql. I was however able to find ways to do this using sqlalchemy orm but not using expression language.So I am specifically looking for core / expression language based solutions. The databases lie on the same server

This is how my connection looks like:

```
connection = engine.connect().execution_options(
schema_translate_map = {current_database_schema: new_database_schema})
engine_1=create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:user@*******/DB_1")
engine_2=create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:user@*******/DB_2",pool_size=5)

metadata_1=MetaData(engine_1)
metadata_2=MetaData(engine_2)

metadata.reflect(bind=engine_1)
metadata.reflect(bind=engine_2)

table_1=metadata_1.tables['table_1']
table_2=metadata_2.tables['table_2']
query=select([table_1.c.name,table_2.c.name]).select_from(join(table_2,table_1.c.id==table_2.c.id,'left')

result=connection.execute(query).fetchall()
```

However, when I try to join tables from different databases it throws an error obviously because the connection belongs to one of the databases. And I haven't tried anything else because I could not find a way to solve this.
Another way to put the question (maybe) is 'how to connect to multiple databases using a single connection in sqlalchemy core'.

Comment: That solution does not seem to work. Throws a key error when table is accessed using metadata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564369/join-tables-in-two-databases-using-sqlalchemy) to Core only you could create a single `Engine` object that connects to your server, but without defaulting to one database or the other:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:user@*******/")
```

and then using a single `MetaData` instance reflect the contents of each schema:

```
metadata = MetaData(engine)
metadata.reflect(schema='DB_1')
metadata.reflect(schema='DB_2')

# Note: use the fully qualified names as keys
table_1 = metadata.tables['DB_1.table_1']
table_2 = metadata.tables['DB_2.table_2']
```

You could also use one of the databases as the "default" and pass it in the URL. In that case you would reflect tables from that database as usual and pass the `schema=` keyword argument only when reflecting the other database.

Use the created engine to perform the query:

```
query = select([table_1.c.name, table_2.c.name]).\
    select_from(outerjoin(table1, table_2, table_1.c.id == table_2.c.id))

with engine.begin() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(query).fetchall()
```

Comment: Hi. Very new to this all. Can I ask whether you missed out any steps between reflecting the metadata and then building the query? Why did you not use ```Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)``` and ```Base.prepare()```?