# Aggregation function on multiple databases in sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

i have two databases in postgres server named as dispatch and drivers and have configured it like this :

```
engines = {    'drivers':create_engine('postgres://postgres:admin@localhost:5432/drivers'),    'dispatch':create_engine('postgres://postgres:admin@localhost:5432/dispatch')
}
```

and also i have routingSession class which based on the object passsed at runtime to the query ,excutes the query at particular database and extract the result

```
class RoutingSession(Session):
    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):
        if mapper and issubclass(mapper.class_, drivers):
            return engines['drivers']
        elif mapper and issubclass(mapper.class_, dispatch):
            return engines['dispatch']
```

so now i can post query on database tables like this :

```
Session = sessionmaker(class_=RoutingSession)
session=Session()
res=session.query(drivers).all()
```

but the problem i am facing is that i need to do aggreagation of results  between my two tables i.e drivers and dispatch ,which i am able to do when working on same database and multiple schemas :

```
result=session.query(drivers,dispatch).filter(drivers.id==dispatch.id).all()
```

but fails when i try to do it on different databases.please suggest how can i achieve this .

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: updated ..please check

Comment: Though it feels like you should be using schema, as you've noted, try reading on foreign data wrappers or dblink, if you must have separate databases.

Comment: @IljaEverilä i am able to achieve this using schemas in same database ,wanted to test if we can achive the same having multiple databases.And for multiple databases also i am able to fire queries to both databases but not sure how to aggreagate the results together of two different queries.

Comment: seems like a duplicate post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564369/join-tables-in-two-databases-using-sqlalchemy   ..@IljaEverilä the solution you have posted in this link does it  work for postgres as well.

Comment: It's a MySQL specific solution, since in MySQL "database" and "schema" are synonymous. I'd still research FDWs, since the newer versions of Postgresql have pretty nifty features in relation to FDWs and aggregation: https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/postgresql-aggregate-push-down-postgresfdw.

Comment: the names "dispatch" and "drivers" sounds related and wanting to aggregate data between them is an even stronger sign that they are. Unless you have a very strong reason for wanting to have those table in separate databases you will make your life way more difficult that way.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign Data  wrappers is a nice way to do aggregation on multiple data bases or servers.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/08/21/foreign-data-wrappers-postgresql-postgres_fdw/

Or else  you can use pandas as well ,by using pandas we can have our dataframes and then do any kind of aggregartion and manipulation on dataframes.Though i have not done any performance testing using pandas but i am assuming it will be slower compared to first approach.