# How to join tables from multiple database using sqlalchemy orm

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm new to python. I have a doubt in connecting multiple databases and in writing join query with it. My raw query is:

```
 SELECT FD.number, FD.options, DATE_FORMAT(TD.date,"%y-%m-%d") as date, 
T.id,S.name, S.id, CP.id, FL.id from finance.reports FD inner join

finance.details TD on FD.number=TD.number inner join app.trans T on T.id = FD.id inner join app.students S on S.id = T.student_id inner join internal.c_map CP on

 FD.options=CP.mode left join internal.trans_logger FL on FL.number = FD.number Where S.id = "181" order by FD.number desc limit 50
```

Here I used three databases, 
`finance, app, internal`
And the tables from finance db are reports and details,
tables from app db are students and trans,
tables from internal are trans_logger and c_map

That raw query is working. But I need to write the same query using orm. How to bind the databases and to achieve this.

I tried like this, But it's not working,

```
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(binds={
    T1: create_engine("finance"),
    T2: create_engine("internal"),
    T3: create_engine("app")
}
session = Session()
q = (session.query(T1)
            .join(T2, T1.reports.number == T2.details.number)
            .join(T3, T1.students.id == T2.trans.student_id)
            .limit(50)
)
```

I've missed something. Kindly help me to achieve that raw query in orm.

Comment: Not working okay. Any errors / output that you can share.

Comment: Pretty close to being a dupe of [Join tables in two databases using SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564369/join-tables-in-two-databases-using-sqlalchemy)

Comment: @NiranjRajasekaran Bro, Actually It's giving me an output of the wrong query. No errors.

Comment: If you can help, kindly do. I really needed it @IljaEverilä