# How do I fix a 'Argument 'class_' is expected to be of type '<class 'type'>', got '<class 'NoneType'>' error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to follow the solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44567216/11277108 and have the following code:

```
Session = sessionmaker()
Base = automap_base()

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/')

Base.metadata.reflect(engine, schema='belgarath')
Base.metadata.reflect(engine, schema='oncourt')
Base.prepare()

Base.metadata.bind = engine

session = Session()

query = session.query(Base.classes.matches_atp).join(Base.classes.tours_atp)
print(query)
```

However, I'm getting two warnings:

```
SAWarning: Unknown schema content: '  KEY `tournament_id_idx` (`ID_T_G`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */'
  util.warn("Unknown schema content: %r" % line)
```

And:

```
SAWarning: This declarative base already contains a class with the same class name and module name as sqlalchemy.ext.automap.tours_atp, and will be replaced in the 
string-lookup table.
```

And then this error:

```
Argument 'class_' is expected to be of type '<class 'type'>', got '<class 'NoneType'>'
```

It seems clear that the error is occurring because of the second warning but how do I fix this...?

---

### Edit:

I found the offending index, removed it but I'm still getting the second warning and error...

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. including `import`s

Comment: Could you provide all your code

Comment: Can you also provide your database schemes. The warning suggest that both databases contain a table or tables with the same name.

Comment: You could try to pass the Base only as a parameter